# How to run a Qt program as a service in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I've written a C++ console application using Qt for an embedded board, I've put the binary file of the program in the startup of the Ubuntu. So whenever the system reboots, My applications starts to work. But sometimes the application crashes and I don't know why !!! I don't want my system to be idle in these situations. Since I want my program to restart after sudden crashing I thought of two possible solutions: 
1. use a hardware watchdog timer, so whenever I reset the timer, the system goes on ... or
2. set my application as an Ubuntu service so in case of crashing it will restart it or it might reboot the system so my application starts again.

the first one is not presented in my board and I don't want to use an external watchdog timer so I wonder if I could do the latter !

P.S.
a software watchdog timer is not reliable so plz don't propose to use a software WD timer !!!
What do you think ? what Can I do ?
Thanks

Comment: What if first you debug your app to see why it crashes ? And why the software watchdog is not reliable ?

Comment: My program doesn't crash normally !! but Since this system is going to be installed in outdoor environment under severe weather condition that we don't have access to this board. so I want to make sure if anything goes out of hand, The operating system could handle it. Software WD Timer is unreliable since it is just a software and software can crash just like my program !

Comment: Ok finally understood what you mean. I think monit will be the easier and better option,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK my suggestion is to use [Monit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/monit) you can install it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install monit
```

with this tool you can monitor via Web, even send email if the process crashes. Of course in your case you can just sent a timeout to restart the application. The best would be to build a simple logging system of your application so it would be easier to trigger the timeout if it crashes.

But first you need to set your application in a upstart service. Take a look at you `/etc/init.d/` directory because you can use some of this files as an example.

Comment: Thanks Dear Imedinas.. I don't have access to the board via web ... it's only RS232 serial port. I want the Operating system to do all the things needed for restarting the application without my interference. But thanks for the second part of your answer (init.d) I'll take a look at it

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clean enough. With monit, it can restart the application automatically using a timeout.

Comment: Okay, Then let me check it and see if it works then I'll hit the answer . Thanks

Comment: Please check this sources [ubuntu services using monit](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/monitoring-ubuntu-services-using-monit.html) and [how to install monit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-monit).

Comment: Imedinas I think this program needs my application to be a service ... how can I run my program as a service in ubuntu ?!!!

Comment: Another alternative is to have a shell script for restarting the application if it crashes. http://askubuntu.com/questions/48768/shell-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-outputs-a-certain-piece-of-text

Comment: Use as an example one of the script in /etc/init.d and start you application in background. ./app &

Comment: An example how to do it: http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/